# Truffle is not working for compiling and deploying

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo, truffle, compile

Is anybody here still using Truffle in order to compile and deploy Tezos projects? I created a project with it over a year ago and wanted to update the environment. After dowloading the latest Ligo compiler, it seems that Truffle is not really up-to-date it is trying to use a non-existing subcommand "compile-contract" when executing truffle compile, which seems to be replaced by compile contract ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use Truffle. Truffle stopped updating the Tezos Suite after they were bought by Consensys. (Tezos Truffle Issues on Github: [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20tezos), [Trufflesuite](https://github.com/trufflesuite/trufflesuite.com/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20tezos)) Their only focus is Ethereum. At this point they are just honoring the existing contracts and accept merge requests for updates. If someone wants to make truffle work one can work on it and create MR.

I suggest to use alternatives like:

- [Chinstrap](https://chinstrap.io/)
- [Taquito](https://opentezos.com/dapp/deploy/deploy-with-taquito)
- [Lava](https://github.com/uconomy/lava)
- [Taqueria](https://taqueria.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Truffle, as far as I know, doesn't support Tezos anymore.
Check out chinstrap. I haven't really used it, but it looks pretty similar to truffle.
https://chinstrap.io/